# where does laravel controller function returns its response?

Tags: laravel-5

where does laravel controller function returns its response?

I have an APICONTROLLER and it has a function test() which returns a response as

`return response()->json($response);`

Now, where does the control goes from here?

Comment: https://cdn.auth0.com/blog/laravel-auth/mvc-diagram.png
Check this. I am sure it will helpful

Comment: yes it helped thanks!!